# Hibernate EntityManager keeps old data

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager

I have Java EE application with Hibernate. I want to implement a feature that every minute updates one of existing rows in database. I have following classes:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class TimerRunnerImpl implements TimerRunner {

    @EJB
    private WorkProcessor workProcessor;

    private String jobId;

    @Timeout
    @AccessTimeout(value = 90, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    @TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
    public void doProcessing(Timer timer) {
        jobId = workProcessor.doWork(jobId);
    }
    //other methods: startTimer, etc
}

@Stateless
public class WorkProcessorImpl implements WorkProcessor {

    @EJB
    private MyEntityDao myEntityDao;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Override
    public String doWork(String jobId) {
        if (jobId == null) {
            MyEntity myEntity = myEntityDao.oldestEntityToProcess();
            String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            myEntity.setJobId(uuid);
            myEntityDao.update(myEntity); // this invokes merge()
            return uuid;
        } else {
            // line below can never find entity, although there is one in DB
            MyEntity myEntity = myEntityDao.findByJobId(jobId); 
            myEntity.setSomeProperty("someValue");
            // some other updates
            myEntityDao.update(myEntity); // this invokes merge()
            return jobId;
        }
    }
}
```

First run of doWork updates MyEntity with job ID. This is being persisted into database - I can query it manually from SQLDeveloper. Second run always fails to find entity by job ID. In case I try to retrieve it by entity_id in debug mode, the object retrieved from Entity Manager has job id with previous value.

This is not cache problem, I have tried on each run to evict all cache at the beginning and results are identical.

As far as I understand, transaction is around workProcessor.doWork(jobId). I find confirmation of this by the fact that when this method returns I can see changes in DB. But why does EntityManager keeps my unmodified object and returns it when I query for it?

Comment: Is the method `myEntityDao.findByJobId(jobId);` tested and works correct? (Apart from this one case above)

Comment: Yes, it's being invoked from JSF context and works correctly there